# SMTP HTML email not rendering HTML via Gmail email client

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp, html-email

I am sending an email via C# SMTP. It's a HTML email which separates lines by 
 tags, e.g. :

> Dear Test,
> A password request has been initiated for your
>   account.  Please click this link....

This renders fine in an Outlook inbox, but in Gmail it seemingly ignores the 
 tags:

**Gmail**
[image: p]

**Outlook**
[image]

Why isn't Gmail rendering the HTML? It's the same result via the web browser as the Android email client.

When I view the source of the Gmail email and download the .eml file from Gmail the email contains the br tags.

I tried replacing the br tags with line breaks, but when I do that the opposite happens - it doesn't render the line breaks in Outlook but it does render them in Gmail.

What's actually going on here and how can I satisfy all email clients?

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

Here is my C# for generating the emails:

```
var mailMessage = new MailMessage
{
    Subject = subject,
    BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
    From = new MailAddress(EmailFrom),
    IsBodyHtml = true
};

var htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body.ReplaceLineBreaksWithHtmlLineBreak(), new ContentType("text/html"));
htmlView.ContentType.CharSet = Encoding.UTF8.WebName;
mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

var plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body.StripHtml(), new ContentType("text/plain"));
plainView.ContentType.CharSet = Encoding.UTF8.WebName;
mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(plainView);
```

For the HTML email, I replace line breaks in my template string with br tags. For the plain text view, any HTML is stripped out.

UPDATE: 
It turns out on my plaintext view I was accidentally stripping out the line breaks. This solves the problem but another question I have is why does Gmail seemingly only render the plaintext version of the email?

Comment: You never set the actual body of your email? Probably your view htmlView is redundant. Just set the body to the HTML. You only need an alternate view for your plainView.

Comment: You should better use string builder to render HTML on mail body.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron What does that have to do with anything?

Comment: @mason as you suggested, I set the body of the HTML and only added an alternative view for the plaintext version but when I done that the HTML tags ended up being displayed on the rendered email for some reason.